# Palindrome problem - Trying to check 2 lists for equality python3.9

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a program to check if a given user input is a palindrome or not. if it is the program should print "Yes", if not "no".  I realize that this program is entirely too complex since I actually only needed to check the whole word using the reversed() function, but I ended up making it quite complex by splitting the word into two lists and then checking the lists against each other.

Despite that, I'm not clear why the last conditional isn't returning the expected "Yes" when I pass it "racecar" as an input.   When I print the lists in line 23 and 24, I get two lists that are identical, but then when I compare them in the conditional, I always get "No" meaning they are not equal to each other.  can anyone explain why this is?  I've tried to convert the lists to strings but no luck.

```
def odd_or_even(a):  # function for determining if odd or even
    if len(a) % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

the_string = input("How about a word?\n")
x = int(len(the_string))

odd_or_even(the_string)  # find out if the word has an odd or an even number of characters

if odd_or_even(the_string) == True:    # if even                     
    for i in range(x):
        first_half = the_string[0:int((x/2))]  #create a list with part 1
        second_half = the_string[(x-(int((x/2)))):x]  #create a list with part 2
else: #if odd
    for i in range(x):
        first_half = the_string[:(int((x-1)/2))] #create a list with part 1 without the middle index
        second_half = the_string[int(int(x-1)/2)+1:] #create a list with part 2 without the middle index

print(list(reversed(second_half)))
print(list(first_half))

if first_half == reversed(second_half):  ##### NOT WORKING BUT DONT KNOW WHY #####
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: Comparing list(reversed(second_half)) with list(first_half) is different from comparing first_half with reversed(second_half). The former compares lists of strings, while the latter compares a string with an iterable.

Comment: Ahh thank you.got it - so reversed() returns an iterable?

Comment: Your `for` loops are entirely pointless, the loop variable `i` is not used anywhere. You can also save yourself a lot of clutter if you ditch the all the `int` casting. Replace it with floor division `x//y` where necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite your comments `first_half` and `second_half` are substrings of your input, not lists. When you print them out, you're converting them to lists, but in the comparison, you do not convert `first_half` or `reversed(second_half)`. Thus you are comparing a string to an iterator (returned by `reversed`), which will always be false.

So a basic fix is to do the conversion for the `if`, just like you did when printing the lists out:

```
if list(first_half) == list(reversed(second_half)):
```

A better fix might be to compare as strings, by making one of the slices use a `step` of `-1`, so you don't need to use `reversed`. Try `second_half = the_string[-1:x//2:-1]` (or similar, you probably need to tweak either the even or odd case by one). Or you could use the "alien smiley" slice to reverse the string after you slice it out of the input: `second_half = second_half[::-1]`.

There are a few other oddities in your code, like your `for i in range(x)` loop that overwrites all of its results except the last one. Just use `x - 1` in the slicing code and you don't need that loop at all. You're also calling `int` a lot more often than you need to (if you used `//` instead of `/`, you could get rid of literally all of the `int` calls).

Comment: thank you.  yes - just started learning programming so everything I do seems very over complicated as soon as I look other peoples code/solutions, but I appreciate all the feedback!